# puppet: `Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server` after adding a code to a profile

Tags: bash, puppet

I am a `puppet` newbie.

I have a functional `puppet` installation (both master and agent).

I need to update a profile to check if both `certbot.timer` and `nginx` systemd services are active; if yes, add `renew_hook = service nginx reload` to `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf` files.

Now, I tried to add these snippets to an existing profile (one at a time):

```sh
exec { 'certbot_nginx' :
  command => 'for file in $(find /etc/letsencrypt/renewal -type f); do if [ "$(grep "renew_hook = service nginx reload" $file)" != "renew_hook = service nginx reload" ]; then sed -i 's/\(\[renewalparams\]\)/\1\nrenew_hook = service nginx reload/' $file; fi; done',
  onlyif  => 'systemctl -q is-active certbot.timer && systemctl -q is-active nginx',
}
```

```sh
exec { "bash -c "if [ \"$(systemctl -q is-active certbot.timer && echo $?)\" = \"0\" ] && [ \"$(systemctl -q is-active nginx && echo $?)\" = \"0\" ]; then for file in $(find /etc/letsencrypt/renewal -type f); do if [ \"$(grep \"renew_hook = service nginx reload\" $file)\" != \"renew_hook = service nginx reload\" ]; then sed -i 's/\(\[renewalparams\]\)/\1\nrenew_hook = service nginx reload/' $file; fi; done; fi"" :
  provider => shell,
  command => 'bash -c "if [ \"$(systemctl -q is-active certbot.timer && echo $?)\" = \"0\" ] && [ \"$(systemctl -q is-active nginx && echo $?)\" = \"0\" ]; then for file in $(find /etc/letsencrypt/renewal -type f); do if [ \"$(grep \"renew_hook = service nginx reload\" $file)\" != \"renew_hook = service nginx reload\" ]; then sed -i 's/\(\[renewalparams\]\)/\1\nrenew_hook = service nginx reload/' $file; fi; done; fi"',
}
```

By no matter what I do, I get this error (only when those snippets are in the profile; otherwise the `puppet agent -t` would run successfully):

```sh
# puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Syntax error at 's' at /some/path/profile.pp:19:186 on node my.server.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

---

#### Side notes

(1) Puppet agent version:

```sh
# puppet --version
5.4.0
```

(2) Puppet server version:

```sh
# puppetserver --version
puppetserver version: 2.8.0
```

(3) Server OS: `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`

(4) Client OS: `Debian 9` (I’ve got the error on `Debian 10`, too.)

Comment: You've put literal single quotes into single-quoted strings in both your `Exec`s, around the `sed` expressions.  The code highlighting in the question here can help you spot them, if you need it.  You need to escape those with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

try (also provided in the comment by [@john bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger)):

```rb
exec { 'certbot_nginx' :
  command => 'for file in $(find /etc/letsencrypt/renewal -type f); do if [ "$(grep "renew_hook = service nginx reload" $file)" != "renew_hook = service nginx reload" ]; then sed -i "s/\(\[renewalparams\]\)/\1\nrenew_hook = service nginx reload/" $file; fi; done',
  onlyif  => 'systemctl -q is-active certbot.timer && systemctl -q is-active nginx',
}
```

and:

```rb
exec { 'renew_hook = service nginx reload' :
  provider => shell,
  command => 'bash -c "if [ \"$(systemctl -q is-active certbot.timer && echo $?)\" = \"0\" ] && [ \"$(systemctl -q is-active nginx && echo $?)\" = \"0\" ]; then for file in $(find /etc/letsencrypt/renewal -type f); do if [ \"$(grep \"renew_hook = service nginx reload\" $file)\" != \"renew_hook = service nginx reload\" ]; then sed -i "s/\(\[renewalparams\]\)/\1\nrenew_hook = service nginx reload/" $file; fi; done; fi"',
}
```

What it means is that you have a string like:

```
'some command; sed 's/x/y/''
```

More documentation on [puppet lang data string](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/lang_data_string.html)

> There are four ways to write literal strings in the Puppet language:
>
> - Bare words
> - Single-quoted strings
> - Double-quoted strings
> - Heredocs

Which implies, that your string will terminate after the second `'`.